# Understanding streamplot function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some vector fields using the streamplot function and following some tutorial (I am new to python) I found something like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n=5
x=np.linspace(-3,3,n)
y=np.linspace(-3,3,n)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
# vector field
u=np.cos(X+Y)
v=np.sin(X-Y)
# plot
plt.streamplot(X, Y, u, v, density=2)
plt.show()
```

so far so good, but if I change the meshgrid using for example `n=50`, the plot is almost the same. So what is the purpose of the 2d arrays X and Y in the streamplot function?

Answer (score 0):

When streamplot function called, u and v arrays only have arbitrary values stored which generally correspond to velocities. There is no location information or coordinates exist in these u and v arrays. Then, we can say that purpose of the X and Y arrays in streamplot function are to map coordinate information to the u and v array's values.

In the example you are presenting, changing `n`'s value neither changes boundaries of the domain nor u or v array's velocities. What changing `n`'s value does is increasing the detail in between the domain boundaries. This means that streamplot is allowed to follow the data provided without doing excessive interpolations.

Please observe the detail increase by calling the below code. Array x will be divided into 10 equal pieces whereas y will be divided into 20.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,1,11)
y = np.linspace(0,1,21)
print("10 intervals:", x)
print("20 intervals:", y)
```